# File upload - it deletes the file, but not the path - Symfony2/Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) to add the functionality to upload files, but I have a little problem. I actually copied the functions from the section [`Using Lifecycle Callbacks`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks). Instead of class `Document`, I have a class `Friend` with this:

```
//...
/**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $picture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;
//...
```

The upload and edit work, but I have problem when deleting. I want to have two options -  `Remove the picture` and `Delete the picture`- the first will only set the current path to `null` and the file will remain in the folder where the files are stored while the second will set to path to `null` and will delete the file, too.

The bad news is that I cannot make the path to be `null`. The file is deleted, but the path stays.

This is the function from the documentation:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($picture = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($picture);
        }
    } 

public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }
```

and this is the action in my controller:

```
public function removePictureAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); 
         $friend = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')->find($id);
         $friend->removeUpload();
         $var=null;
         $friend->setPath($var);
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('friend_id', array('id' => $id))); 
    }
```

but the path stays... How to delete it and set it to be null again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist your friend entity and flush the entity manager

Comment: Yes... it's working now. I don't know how to thank you for answering so fast and helpfully to all of my stupid questions!